# Approximating a path in the closed disk by a path in the open disk

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $\gamma: [0,1]\to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ be a path in the closed unit disk.

For $\epsilon>0$, define the following approximation $\gamma_{\epsilon}$, which lies in the open unit disk:

$$
\gamma_{\epsilon}(t)= \begin{cases}
\gamma(t) &\text{if } |\gamma(t)|\leq 1-\epsilon\\
(1-\epsilon)\frac{\gamma(t)}{|\gamma(t)|} &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
In other words, for the parts of $\gamma$ that are outside the $(1-\epsilon)$ disk, we project it onto the $(1-\epsilon)$-circle.

Suppose $\gamma$ is rectifiable.
Is it true that the arclength of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ converges to the arclength of $\gamma$?